# How do I cache an image

Tags: c#, caching

Every time the user presses a button my application gets the image from the web, but this slow since the image isn't getting cached. Any way I can cache the image so it doesn't download it over and over making things faster.
This is my code so you know how my application works.

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {


        richTextBox1.Text = "Explore any game with Dex";
        pictureBox1.Load("THE LINK ");
        ProtoxRe.lol = 0;

    }
    else if ((listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1))
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "SOME TEXT";
        pictureBox1.Load("LINK");
        ProtoxRe.lol = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Store the image in a variable (dealers choice) and then check if the variable isn't null before going to the web. If you want more detail you need to post some demostrating code.

Comment: @WSC Im kind of new to c# can you tell me how to do that? Yes I know thats spoonfeeding but I need help badly

Comment: See [Lazy<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netcore-3.1) or [Polly - MemoryChache/CachePolicy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.Caching.MemoryCache), or even preload the image and reuse the preloaded instance ...

Comment: @Potatox I've added an example, but without some more detail about what you're trying to do it's hard to say how appropriate it is as a solution. If you provide more details I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: If you have a single image to download, store an Image object. If you have more Images, build a class object that holds the resource URI and an Image object (plus whatever else may be useful in your context). Use a `List<class>` to hold your Image references. Before requesting an Images from the Web, check whether that URI is already in store. Download if it's not. -- All Web Requests type provide async methods to retrieve Resources from a Network.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably more sophisticated methods, and this assumes your image is not expected to change, but you can do something like this:

```cs
//Image class is from this library
using System.Drawing;

//The scope of this will depend on where you need to access it from
Image img;

private Image GetImage()
{
    if (img == null)
    {
        img = GetImageFromHttp();
    }
    return img;
}
```

This is very basic, and has a number of flaws; you're not caching it between sessions so every application start will require the http get, and you're not checking if the image on the web is different, but it's a starting point.